# Android: How to set Image size will be same as document page size?

Tags: android, pdf-generation, itext

I am using the iText library to generate PDF document. In such a PDF, I am adding multiple images per page.

[image: iText]

Below is the code to generate PDF.

```
Document document = new Document();

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
writer.setPageEvent(new PageWithRectangle());

document.open();

for (int i = 0; i < listSelected.size(); i++) {
    //PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    //table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    document.newPage();
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listSelected.get(i));
    // Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,
    // bMap.getWidth(),bMap.getHeight(), null, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
    image.setBorder(Image.BOX);
    image.setBorderWidth(10); 
    float documentWidth = document.getPageSize().getWidth()
            - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin();
    float documentHeight = document.getPageSize().getHeight()
            - document.topMargin() - document.bottomMargin();
    image.scaleToFit(documentWidth, documentHeight);

    Log.e("Document - Image  = Height", document.getPageSize().getHeight()+" - "+image.getScaledHeight());

    float leftMargin =  document.getPageSize().getWidth() - image.getScaledWidth();
    float lMargin = leftMargin / 2 ;

    float topMargin =  document.getPageSize().getHeight() - image.getScaledHeight(); 
    float tMargin = topMargin / 2 ;

    image.setAbsolutePosition(lMargin,tMargin);
    /*PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(image);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    table.addCell(cell);*/

    document.add(image);
}
document.close();
```

- Is it possible to set page size to be the same as the image size, so that there's no white top and bottom margin?
- How can i set page as LANDSCAPE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing image into pdf file in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786026/writing-image-into-pdf-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set page size same as image size, so top and bottom white field will not display?

This question was already answered in May 2013: [Writing image into pdf file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786026/writing-image-into-pdf-file-in-java)

> How can i set page as LANDSCAPE?

Right now you are creating a document in the A4 format.

```
Document document = new Document();
```

is the equivalent of:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 36);
```

If you want to create an A4 page with a rotation of 90 degrees (so that portrait becomes landscape), then you can do this:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
```

Of course you can also create a custom `Rectangle` object that has the dimensions you need. That's what the answer to this question is about: [Writing image into pdf file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786026/writing-image-into-pdf-file-in-java)